# C# Получить байты, представленные в виде строки

Tags: c#

У меня есть поле, в нем находятся байты файла (передаются мне извне), и необходимо сохранить их на ПК в файл. Все взаимодействие происходит через **dll** без документации и доступа к исходному коду библиотеки. Могу получить значение только типом *String*. Проблема заключается в том, как мне извлечь байты.
Для понимания вот начало строки:

> 504B030414

А вот мне скинули исходный файл и читаю его в бинарном виде (номер байта : значение байта в DEC):

```
0 : 80
1 : 75
2 : 3
3 : 4
4 : 20
```

Если переводить байты (например калькулятором) в HEX, то получается как раз

> 50 4B 03 04 14

Т.е. получается это HEX строка (если так можно выразиться) возвращается методом и мне необходимо ее перевести в байты для дальнейшей записи в файл. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Выберите кодировку. Если устроит ASCII то так `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(строка)`. Если нет - ф-ция GetEncoding http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding

Comment: Вам байты в строку или строку в байты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
void Main()
{
    var source = "504B030414";
    var data1 = Split(source, 2);
    // data1.Dump();
    byte[] data2 = data1.Select(x => Convert(x)).ToArray();
    // data2.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

static IEnumerable<string> Split(string str, int chunkSize)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length / chunkSize)
        .Select(i => str.Substring(i * chunkSize, chunkSize));
}

static byte Convert(string hex)
{
    var num = int.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    byte[] result = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
    return result[0];
}
```

Вывод (linqpad):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примечание:

- [Разбиение строки на фрагменты определённого размера](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1450774/5752652)

Comment: Может, все таки не будем использовать методы 2009 года? ХД У нас есть `Span<T>` все же ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ + зачем Вам `int.Parse` и уж тем более `BitConverter` для данной задачи? 00...ff и без того укладываются ровно в 1 байт

Answer (score 2):

Ну или например вот так (если вы уверены во входных данных)

```
void Main()
{
    Convert("504B030414").Dump();
}

private static int ConvertHex(char c)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(c)) return c - '0';
    else return c - 'A' + 10;   
}

private static byte[] Convert(string str)
{
    var ret = new byte[str.Length/2];   
    for(int i=0; i<str.Length; i+=2)            
        ret[i/2] = (byte)(ConvertHex(str[i]) * 16 + ConvertHex(str[i+1]));  
    return ret;
}
```

Вывод

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]